# How do I make my python file executable from anywhere in my system and without having to say "python3" and ".py" before and after the file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I am trying to make my python3 file executable from any location in the terminal (on mac os) so that instead of:

```
python3 myFile.py argv1 argv2 argv 3
```

Instead you type

```
myFile argv1 argv2 argv3
```

I can make the file executable via ./myFile but that's not really what I'm looking for and I can't make it executable from anywhere in the system.

Answer (score 3):

Type `which python3` to uncover where you have your python executable. In my case it is `/usr/local/bin/python3` directory.

Your python file should contain a shebang referencing the executable as the first line in the file. So, for example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Next, you must make sure that the file itself is executable.

Some files have different permissions (files can be read / write / execute and by different groups user / group / everyone). Execute on the terminal `sudo chmod +x your_python_file.py`.

Finally, you should add the directory where your file script is saved to your system $PATH.

In your terminal execute:

```
cd $HOME && mkdir bin
```

Put your python script in this bin directory. Then add the bin directory to your system `$PATH` by running:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thanks, most of it is working except I can't access the python script anywhere but the directory in which it is stored e.g. if it is stored in my user directory, I can't access it in my desktop.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it works and the solution is acceptable, please accept it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's all working fine now :)

Comment: That's wonderful Jacob. Could you accept my answer and upvote it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To make it executable without saying `python` first, put

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

as the first line and make the file executable.

To make it executable from any location, put the script in a directory that's in your `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for commenting so quick - I'm a bit confused about your second part and the first part doesn't seem to be working - I get the message "zsh: operation not permitted: ./filename.py" - even in sudo. I mean I'm pretty inexperienced.

Comment: Check the filesystem mount options, make sure it doesn't have `noexec`.